# Gracefully ignore invalid dates with a NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database. It is using MySQL Version 5.7, which has a feature where the `sql_mode` setting includes NO_ZERO_DATE:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Variable_name: sql_mode
        Value: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

There was an invalid date inserted into one of the tables, which prevented ALTER TABLE from working. The invalid date:

```
+---------------------+
| activity_time       |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
```

I resolved the issue by manually doing this:

```
 UPDATE students 
 SET activity_time = NULL
 WHERE activity_time < '0000-01-01 00:00:00';
```

But how can I configure the table to silently convert invalid dates to NULL so that the ALTER TABLE command will always continue to work?

Comment: Which `ALTER TABLE` command are you trying to run?

Comment: @GMB ALTER TABLE students MODIFY COLUMN comments TEXT;

Comment: Typically you wouldn't _want_ to make table alters a part of your program as much as part of a migration.

Comment: You may want to explicitly `NULL` your invalid dates to avoid all these wonky checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only chance that i see is to use trigger, to chekc before insert and update

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_students_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON students FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.activity_time < '0000-01-01 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.activity_time = NULL;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_students_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON students FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.activity_time < '0000-01-01 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.activity_time = NULL;
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Thsi would work silently.

A CHECK Constarint(since Version8) would not allow to save the row, but it would not work silently

Comment: Just to observe that this is for a specific set of invalid dates. Yes, it includes the problem date identified, but it is not the set of all invalid dates.

Comment: he run  the update query for all existing dates, so that the oast is secure, and in future will not be more ivqalif d ates on this column.